# Can a C/C++ program be compiled into a .NET portable class library using C++/CLI

Tags: c++-cli, portable-class-library, cil

I've read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/68td296t.aspx) on .NET programming in C++/CLI, and understand at a high level that it can compile C or C++ to .NET MSIL. I also understand that native structures are translated in the process.

The question is, can I compile a C/C++ codebase into a .NET Portable Class Library using C++/CLI? The intention is to use the result across various platforms, e.g. the Xamarin platforms and UWP.

Edit: Is it easier to do this for plain C, rather than C++?

Comment: No.  There is nothing "portable" about C++/CLI, it requires a module initializer to get the CRT initialized and that eliminates .NETCore.  Which eliminates just about all targets, you need Windows and the full version of the framework.  The language is often confused with C++/CX, a language extension that supports WinRT (aka UWP), syntax is very similar.  But is purely native.  These language extensions solve the same problem, interfacing native C++ to a foreign type system, and therefore look quite similar.

Comment: Hans, good point. Can the CRT requirement be worked around? In other words, can I supply an implementation of just the used CRT functions that call in to the CLR libraries?

Comment: You have the CRT source code on your machine.  Ought to be convincing enough that such a plan will never go anywhere.

Comment: *"at a high level [...] it can compile C or C++ to .NET MSIL"* - No, C++/CLI cannot do that. It compiles standard C and C++ code to platform and architecture specific object code. C++/CLI offers language extensions, that allow you to define `ref class`es, that get compiled to MSIL. But it won't just take any standard C or C++ code and compile it into portable MSIL code.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: AFAIK no.

Long answer:

As far as I know the C++/CLI source code is compiled in "mixed" mode. It means that if you learn C++/CLI language and create managed classes with it, they run in .NET natively. That's good. But if you simply take your existing C++ code and compile it, the result is the native x86/Windows code, which cannot be used on other platforms. It is called "mixed" because the compiler puts native and .NET IL code together to single executable file.

C++/CLI is usually used in situations where you want to use the existing C++ code
as a part of .NET program in Windows. So you create a library in C++/CLI and create an interface for it in managed C++/CLI. This managed C++/CLI interface is a bridge between native C++ code and the rest of your program in .NET.

Also, as far as I know, C++/CLI is generally not supported by CoreCLR.

Comment: I do not think that is correct - look up the /clr:pure compiler switch. My question is more specific - about whether the resulting MSIL can be packaged (easily or otherwise) into a Portable Class Library.

Comment: Only subset of C++ can be compiled in clr:pure mode. So the question is: Does your code successfully compile?

Comment: The question is about whether the approach is sound in general. If there are caveats or limitations to the approach then an answer might discuss those. As it stands, your answer is factually incorrect - it states that there is no way to avoid native code - and so should be amended, or removed.

Comment: @bright: you'd have to declare `ref class` types in C++/CLI to get something usable from the outside. Plain C++ `class` types won't be visible outside of the assembly that defines them. This answer is right in that you can't cut corners here, you'll have to write some bridge code.

Comment: Lucas, I don't mind bridge code at all. The question invites *any* method of producing a PCL using C++/CLI. Would you like to elaborate into a usable answer? Your comment is appreciated. The question also asks about plain C. Is C easier to compile via C++/CLI into a PCL?

Comment: @bright see Hans' comment on the question, unfortunately PCL is out of the picture. A C interface would be useful for consumption by P/Invoke from any .NET language, which could be an alternative to C++/CLI. I don't know about usage on UWP/Xamarin though as I've never used them.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski, I responded to Hans' comment and asked if it is possible to work around the CRT issue. Do you have any thoughts on the same question? As far as P/Invoke, that would require separate native builds for each platform, which I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @bright You'll always need separate native builds for each platform, even with C++/CLI. The only way AFAIK to remove the CRT dependency is to use `/clr:pure`, which defeats the purpose of C++/CLI.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski - I was referring to `/clr:pure` all along :) What do you mean exactly by defeats the purpose? My goal is to use C code in a cross platform .net app. C++/CLI is what I'm investigating to help achieve this. What is wrong with `/clr:pure`?

Comment: @bright C++/CLI's really useful feature is the ability to produce mixed mode assemblies. And if your C code uses the standard library you'll need to link it with the native CRT. There's no magic involved unfortunately, unless your C code is trivial you'll have a hard time trying to make it work as-is without native parts. Oh, IIRC you'll also need to hack the output assembly to mark it as AnyCPU, even in pure mode, as it's not supported out of the box.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski: My takeaway then is that for C code that does *not* use the standard library - and there are such cases that I'm interested in - the `clr:pure` switch is still a contender. To be honest, I don't know why all the comments have been negative - focused on the "not possible", instead of just outlining the cases, however narrow, in which it *is* possible. Negative answers are much harder to work through.

Comment: @bright: You cannot compile C code to MSIL. C code and `/clr:pure` have no intersection. Other than deterministic destruction, there is zero reason to choose C++/CLI with the `/clr:pure` compiler switch.